# Find the minimum difference between any pair of elements between two vectors

Tags: matlab

Which of the following statements will find the minimum difference between any pair of elements (a,b) where a is from the vector A and b is from the vector B.

```
A. [X,Y] = meshgrid(A,B);
   min(abs(X-Y))
B. [X,Y] = meshgrid(A,B);
   min(abs(min(Y-X)))
C. min(abs(A-B))
D. [X,Y] = meshgrid(A,B);
   min(min(abs(X-Y)))
```

Can someone please explain to me?

Comment: Why don't you try your options for a small example: `A=[1 2 3];B=[2.25 4 -2];`

Comment: C will give you the minimum

Comment: @David, yeah I got my error , I believe D will give the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
D. [X,Y] = meshgrid(A,B);
   min(min(abs(X-Y)))
```

[`meshgrid`](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) will generate two grids - X and Y - from the vectors, which are arranged so that `X-Y` will generate all combinations of ax-bx where ax is in a and bx is in b.

The rest of the expression just gets the minimum absolute value from the array resulting from the subtraction, which is the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

By saying "minimum difference between any pair of elements(a,b)", I presume you mean that you are treating A and B as sets and you intend to find the absolute difference in *any possible* pair of elements from these two sets. So in this case you should use your option D

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(A,B);
min(min(abs(X-Y)))
```

Explanation: Meshgrid turns a pair of 1-D vectors into 2-D grids. This link can explain what I mean to say:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

Hence (X-Y) will give the difference in all possible pairs (a,b) such that a belongs to A and b belongs to B. Note that this will be a 2-D matrix.

abs(X-Y) would return the absolute values of all elements in this matrix (the absolute difference in each pair).

To find the smallest element in this matrix you will have to use min(min(abs(X-Y))). This is because if Z is a matrix, min(Z) treats the columns of Z as vectors, returning a row vector containing the minimum element from each column. So a single min command will give a row vector with each element being the min of the elements of that column. Using min for a second time returns the min of this row vector. This would be the smallest element in the entire matrix.

This can help:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html?searchHighlight=min

Options C is correct if you treat A and B as vectors and not sets. In this case you won't be considering all possible pairs. You'll end up finding the minimum of (a-b) where a,b are both in the same position in their corresponding vectors (pair-wise difference).

Answer (score 0):

CORRECT ANSWER IS D

Let `m = size(A)` and `n = size(B)`
You want to subtract each pair of `(a,b)` such that a is from vector A and b is from vector B.
`meshgrid(A,B)` creates two matrices `X Y` both of size `nxm` where `X` have rows sames have vector `A` while `Y`has columns same as vector `B` . 
Hence , `Z = X-Y` will give you a matrix with `n*m` values corresponding to the difference between each pair of values taken from `A` and `B`  . Now all you have to do is to find the absolute minimum among all values of `Z`.

You can do that by
    `req_min = min(min(abs(z)))`

The whole code is

```
[X Y ] = meshgrid(A,B);
Z=  X-Y;
Z = abs(Z);
req_min = min(min(Z));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead of `meshgrid`:

```
min(min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A(:), B(:).'))))
```

Or use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html):

```
min(min(pdist2(A(:),B(:))))
```